# Will increasing difficulty always be an issue when using bows?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've just started up a Demon Hunter, and upon entering the Tristram Cathedral, I noticed that I was having a very difficult time getting things to die. I realized that this was due to the fact that unlike other characters I've tried out so far, I've been hanging on to my rather pathetic starter weapon, having come across no bows/crossbows.

While I understand it is possible to use a Demon Hunter without equipping a bow, that is not really the case early in the game (most of my skills won't work without bows, and these are the skills that generate hatred). I am seriously considering buying a weapon, something I haven't had to do yet this early in the game.

So assuming I want the option of using skills that require bows - will I constantly find myself at a disadvantage when the difficulty ramps up until I manage to come across a suitably powerful bow, or does this problem become less prominent as the game progresses?

Comment: Radek the Fence, just outside the main town area, sells a variety of crossbows. Purchasing one of these early in the game will increase the damage you can deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find yourself disadvantaged greatly, I've experienced this a lot when switching difficulties with my level 60 Demon Hunter. There are 2 options though:

1. Farm the act/difficulty which suits you best. (Takes a lot of time.)
2. Buy a better buy at the auction house. (Takes a lot of gold.)

Generally, I pick **option 2** because of time constraints. Do mind that the bows you will need are cheap at early difficulties, but ramp up to 1 million gold each for a decent 2-handed (cross)bow on Inferno.

Also, **increased attack speed** on other items will make your DPS go up, if buying a new bow each act or difficulty seems wasteful.

Comment: Getting an upgraded bow that has considerably more damage on it helps immensely.  You go from two or three-shotting simple mobs to one-shotting almost everything.

Comment: I agree, a better bow is better than just some IAS, but IAS is just a (possibly) cheaper option to buying a new bow.

Comment: My, this sounds very inconvenient. I guess I'll see if this eventually breaks me. Thanks for the input!